# Regex email address list parser doesn't pick up last item in list

Tags: regex

[Here is the regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/43RnKi/1).

I want to parse a list of email addresses separated by a variety of delimiters. The regex I am using is:

```
/(\S+?@\S+?\.\S+?)[,|;|\|\s|\n|\r|\t|\0|\b|$]/gmi
```

The problem is, [in the example demo above](https://regex101.com/r/43RnKi/1), it doesn't pick up the last item in the list. How do I pick up the last email address in the list?

Comment: You don't need alternation-pipes inside a character class, they are just treated as literal pipes - as almost any other character, e.g. $. You might use `(?:[delimiters]|$)`. Is `\b` indeed supposed to be a backspace?

Comment: You don't have to use a single regex to solve every problem.  I'm guessing you're using Perl, so use `split` to split on the delimiters, and then address the email addresses themselves.  (Also, the `/i` flag is not helpful here)

Comment: For a reason that still evades me, it works if the input has a trailing line. Using `/(\S+?@\S+?\.\S+?)[,;\\\s\n\r\t\0\b$]/gi` which seems more correct doesn't change anything

Comment: Aaaah, found it : you can't use `$` in a character class (`\b` probably doesn't work either, that must extend to any 0-length meta-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$` as a line/string terminator inside a character class, it will be understood as the literal dollar character : while `/(\S+?@\S+?\.\S+?)[,|;|\|\s|\n|\r|\t|\0|\b|$]/gmi` doesn't work, `/(\S+?@\S+?\.\S+?)([,|;|\|\s|\n|\r|\t|\0|\b|]|$)/gmi` does.

Additionally, I would suggest a number of improvements to your regex :

- remove the pipes from the character class, unless you want to match a literal pipe
- remove the `NUL` (`\0`) character from the character class. Not only should it never appear in your string, even if it did it would be matched by `$`
- remove the linefeeds from your character class and/or stop using the `m` flag, unless a single address can be split in multiple lines
- stop using the `i` flag, which won't affect the character classes you're using

I also doubt you want to match `centralreservation@ramaya;nahotel.com` as a valid address.

In conclusion, I suggest you use [`[^\s;,@]+@[^\s;,@]+\.[^\s;,@]+`](https://regex101.com/r/trmyUl/4) instead, or better stop trying to validate email addresses with regex and instead use a specialized library. To understand why, check [the regex this perl module](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) uses to validate emails. And it doesn't even fully implement the RFC...

A big thanks to Sebastian Proske for his assistance.

Comment: In character classes almost every character is treated as literal character. Exceptions are `^` at the start, `-` between 2 other characters, `]` anywhere but at the start and \. There is no need for alternation pipes inside a character class. `\b` is a backspace character when inside a character class. If you use `\s`, there is no need for `\r`, `\t` or `\n`

Comment: Yeah, I was in the process of adding suggestions but wanted to give the real answer first. I think an english specification would be better because this still looks overcomplicated.

Comment: The last regex doesn't work, e.g. it matches the mail addresses from the second line as a single one.

Comment: Woops, right, thanks for proofreading. I shouldn't do regex when I'm tired

Comment: Well now I've got `[^\s;,]+?@[^\s;,]+?\.[^\s;,]+` which works, but I'm not sure it's better than the first one. It will avoid matching non-space parameters inside the non-last-level domain names as a plus I think

Comment: You could als add `@` to the negated character classes and make them greedy, not lazy. Note that there might be valid e-mail-adresses using `,`, `;`, spaces or multiple `@`s